# I have a problem with trying to resolved this undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

And they search on User ID for a default state account
/features/step-definitions/searches/account_searching.rb:8:in `/^they search on (.*) for a (.*)$/' features/features/search/account.feature:35:in` they search on User ID for a default state account'

```
When(/^they search on (.*) with '(.*)'$/) do |search_field, search_text|
  @searched_value = search_text
  @searched_field = @page.account_search(search_text, search_field)

 
  logger.info "Account Search on: #{search_field} with #{search_text} completed"

  @page = AccountSearchResults.new
  @page.displayed?
end
```

I have tried with creating variables added this below
@hagrid[:account_searching][:search_text] = search_text

and expect it to display all the state account details but fall over

Comment: Would you mind formatting your question a bit? It seems to be output, code and text.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any `[]=` method calls in this snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that @hagrid[:account_searching] is assigned to Hash before you try to add a key/value to it

```
@hagrid[:account_searching] ||= {}

@hagrid[:account_searching][:search_text] = 'some text'
```